# laravel: BelongsToMany with two diffrent mysql connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have a 2 diffrent mysql connection

1 - mysql db

categories table
2 - articles db

article table
articles_categories table
i try to make a relationship with the two tables with a difrrent mysql conacction

but i get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'articles.categories' doesn't exist (SQL: select `categories`.*, `articles_categories`.`article_id` as `pivot_article_id`, `articles_categories`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id` from `categories` inner join `articles_categories` on `categories`.`id` = `articles_categories`.`category_id` where `articles_categories`.`article_id` = 7)
categories db is inside mysql table and article and articles_categories is inside the articles db connaction
```

this is my code:

```
  public function categories(){

return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category','articles_categories','article_id','category_id');
```

i think the laravel try to find the categories table in articles db but the categories table is inside the mysql db

thanks

Comment: Have you specified the connection in he `Category` class?

Comment: @apokryfos yes but i didnt know how to say to laravel the categories  table is in a diffrent sql connaction

Comment: I meant the `$connection` variable in the model. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models where it says *Database Connection*

Comment: @apokryfos yes i do that and i get a difrrent error: 
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mysql.articles_categories' -> this table articles_categories is in articles sql connaction and i try to make that but i get the same error: return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Article\Article','articles.articles_categories');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to specify the connection of the other model explicitly:

```
class Category extends Model {
     protected $connection = 'mysql';
}
```

Then it's best to be very explicit about the names of your pivot table:

```
public function categories(){
     $defaultConnection = config('database.default');
     $defaultDatabase = config("database.connections.$defaultConnection.database");
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category',"$defaultDatabase.articles_categories",'article_id','category_id');
}
```

This will try to ensure that the relationship uses the `articles_categories` table in the default connection and not the connection specified in `Category` .